# Grouping the scenarios in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs

how we can group the scenarios and run using test runner?
I am using cucumber selenium, and need to group the scenarios.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are looking to do. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score -1):

Categories - use whichever method the your chosen unit testing framework uses(assuming you're using one)

Junit
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0

TestNG
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_group_test.htm

Nunit
http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2

Comment: I guess if you aren't using a unit test framework with them then you're stuck to tagging the tests?  https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Comment: Note that the wiki is scheduled to be deleted, go to the documentation instead: https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tags